# What is the purpose of quantification over the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

This question is rather short, but I couldn't find the specific answer I was looking for anywhere.

**My understanding so far:** (Please correct me if I am wrong on some of this)

- I can assume any statement $P(x)$ for all $x \in \emptyset$ to be true because the empty set doesn't contain any elements in the first place.
- I can also assume any statement $Q(x)$ to be false for all $x \in \emptyset$ because of the same reason.
- An example would be $ \forall M \subseteq \emptyset $ where $M \neq \emptyset$, it holds that $M = \emptyset$ . This statement has to be true for all subsets $M$  because the premise (there are no subsets of $\emptyset$ which are not the empty set themselves) is false.

**My question:** What is this good for? Is this behavior just a trivial property of the empty set? The only usage that comes to my mind is if I want to prove something specific for the empty set itself (for example that $\emptyset$ is an ordinal).

Comment: What do you mean with a function to be "true" or "false" ?

Comment: @Peter I assumed the word "function" here should actually be (logical) "predicate".

Comment: I edited the post and changed the word function to statement. I also tried to make clear what I wanted to say in the example.

Comment: No you can *not* assume any statement to be false for all $Q(x)$.  You *MUST* assume all statements are true for all $x \in \emptyset$.  That does mean that both a statement and the negation of a statement are both true for all $x \in \emptyset$ but an negation of a statement being true over an empty does *not* imply a statement is false over an empty set.

Comment: It happens that quantifying over the empty set can lead to some jokes, e.g. "during all my years as King of England, I was a perfect ruler".

Comment: That's a good purpose! @FiMePr

Answer (score 2):

Be careful: $P(x)$ is not a statement, unless $x$ is a constant.
If $x$ is a variable, then, $P(x)$ is a propositional function and
its truth value is, in general, undetermined.

The statement: $\forall xP(x)$, is false, if there are values of
$x$, for which, $P(x)$ is false. The statement: "$\forall x\in\varnothing P(x)$",
is always true, since $\varnothing$ has no members. But, this is
actually an abbreviation for:
$$\forall x\left[x\in\varnothing\rightarrow P(x)\right]$$
This is true, because, if $A$ is always false, $A\rightarrow B$
is always true. So, when you say:

> I can assume any statement $P(x)$ for all $x\in\varnothing$ to
> be true because the empty set doesn't contain any elements in the
> first place.

This is not right. You should not assume $P(x)$ to be true. You should
only assume "*For all $x\in\varnothing$, $P(x)$*" to be true. Similarly, you should not assume $Q(x)$ to be false. It has no truth
value. Furthermore, if you assume that "*For all $x\in\varnothing$,
$Q(x)$*" is false, your wrong. This is always a true statement.

Your example, formally expressed, gives the following:
$$\forall M\left[M\subseteq\varnothing\wedge M\neq\varnothing\rightarrow M=\varnothing\right]$$

Since "$M\subseteq\varnothing\wedge M\neq\varnothing$" is always
false (for every value of $M$), then  "$M\subseteq\varnothing\wedge M\neq\varnothing\rightarrow M=\varnothing$" is always true. Thus, the above is a true statement. But from this, you could never conclude: "*$M\neq\varnothing$ and $M=\varnothing$*".